# php bin/magento setup:upgrade, could not open input file:magento

Tags: magento

When executing command from Magento root folder home/magento_ftp/www/:
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
error returns;
Could not open input file:magento

Magento 2.2.3 is on a Varnix server and /var folder has 777 permissions on the magento file owner. Also running magento setup:upgrade from within the bin does not work. magento file exists in /bin.
Also tried to delete all files in /var.

How can I see which prevents magento from running setup:upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing file `home/magento_ftp/www/bin/magento`. See if there is a **bin** folder in the magento root.